# Rstudio - lattice package plots make other plots disappear in compiled html report

Tags: r

I want to use the compile notebook feature of Rstudio to create an html report of some R code that includes some plots.

When I include a lattice xyplot in my code, the html report does not include other plots that should be there and only shows the most recent lattice plot.

Probably easiest to show in example and see if anyone can replicate my problem:

```
# Create some data:
time <- seq(0, 9.9, 0.1)  
weight <- (time^2) + rnorm(100,0,10)  
temperature <- factor(sample(c("cold", "hot"), 100, replace = TRUE))


# Create matrix to partition layout of graphs
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat)

# Do some plots
plot(weight ~ time, pch = 21, bg = "green")
plot(weight ~ temperature)
plot(weight ~ time, col = c("black", "red")[temperature])
```

When I compile the above to html report (ctrl + shift + k in Rstudio) it looks fine.  However, if I try the exact same code with some additional lattice plots at the end I only see the final plot in the html report:

```
# Create some data:
time <- seq(0, 9.9, 0.1)  
weight <- (time^2) + rnorm(100,0,10)  
temperature <- factor(sample(c("cold", "hot"), 100, replace = TRUE))


# Create matrix to partition layout of graphs
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat)

# Do some plots
plot(weight ~ time, pch = 21, bg = "green")
plot(weight ~ temperature)
plot(weight ~ time, col = c("black", "red")[temperature]) 

# Now try some plots using lattice
library(lattice)

xyplot(weight ~ time | temperature)
xyplot(weight ~ time, groups = temperature)
```

Can anyone else replicate this problem?

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and RStudio Version 0.99.891

EDIT:  There's no issue if I don't use the layout() function to partition a figure.  I can live without that feature for now but if anyone knows why layout() is an issue for rmarkdown/knittr that would be useful to know in future.

Comment: I think you might do better to post on the RStudio support forums as the experts are more likely to be found there.

Comment: will do, thanks for tip

Comment: Seems off topic. Maybe this should be in StackOverflow?

Comment: This might do well on [SO]. Questions asking for coding help are off topic here, but can be on topic there. If you wait, we will try to migrate this for you. Re: posting on the RStudio forum, be aware that a lot of people are offended by cross-posting. I would try only 1 place first, & if you don't get a satisfactory answer, then maybe deleting & posting elsewhere. (Eg, if you want to post on RStudio, I might delete this.)